# JavaScript accessing form elements using document.forms[].elements[]

Tags: javascript, forms, element

```
var loc_name = document.forms['create_<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($window_ID)); ?>'].elements['location_name'];
alert(loc_name);
```

This just gives me the message 'undefined'

where as...

```
var loc_name = document.forms['create_<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($window_ID)); ?>'];
alert(loc_name);
```

Gives me the object form business.

Have I just got this all wrong? What is the 'proper' way to access this form element. The form element has the correct `name` and it has an `id`, the id is similar but not the same.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="create_location" value="Create" onclick="
var pre_row_was = $('#pre_form_row_1').innerHTML;
$('#pre_form_row_1').innerHTML = '&lt;td colspan=\'3\'&gt;Validating...&lt;/td&gt;';
var loc_name = document.forms['create_1'].elements['location_name'];
alert(loc_name);
if(loc_name.value == '') { 
  alert('You can\'t leave the room name blank');
  loc_name.focus(); loc_name.value = 'Enter a name';
  $('#pre_form_row_1').innerHTML = pre_row_was; return false;
}
if(loc_name.value == 'Enter a name') {
  alert('You must enter a room name first'); loc_name.focus();
  $('#pre_form_row_1').innerHTML = pre_row_was;
  return false;
}
$('#pre_form_row_1').innerHTML = pre_row_was;
Window_manager.new_window().load_xml('location/create.php?location_name=' + loc_name.value).display();">
```

tried formatting it so it is easier to read.

Comment: Please show the generated HTML.

Comment: Can you show the *generated* HTML (what the browser's actually seeing), rather than the PHP code? Separately, your best bet for debugging this is to walk through it on the client using a debugger like Chrome's DevTools, Firebug on Firefox, or Visual Studio or the Script Debugger on IE.

Comment: `innerHTML` won't work on a jQuery wrapper, it's a property of DOM nodes. Use `.html()`. And for the love of sanity, kick that JS out of an inline event handler attribute into a `<script>` block assigning a `click(function() { ... })` listener!

Comment: @bobince and others That innerHTML bit is going to be changed in a bit, got other things to work on. It work fine though, if I use a <span> and set the inner HTML of that... the real problem I was having was wanting to leave it empty, but still take up the space of a line of text. using a <br /> seemed to work well enough though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

A `tr` element cannot have a `form` child, and a `form` cannot have a `td` child.

Browsers recover from this error in different ways, including (if I remember correctly) moving the form element to after the table while leaving everything else where it is.

Start with a [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) document before you try to access the DOM with JS.

When mixing forms and tables you can entire put the entire table in a form, or an entire form in a cell.

A further problem you have is an attempt to modify the innerHTML of a table row. This will break in many versions of Internet Explorer. Never modify *bits* of a table with innerHTML.

Comment: I don't think I have ever had such an issue before. I think I have solved it just by moving the form tags so they are completely outside of the table tags. I think the way form tags work is flawed in the first place. You should just form elements that you have to give an ID, then any form elements with the form ID are considered one form, where ever those elements are on the page... oh well. Thanks

Comment: @thecoshman: *"I think I have solved it just by moving the form tags so they are completely outside of the table tags"* Right. That's what David said: You can put the entire table in the form (whereupon it's perfectly valid for the form *elements* to be inside cells). But you can't have `table > tbody > form > tr` or `table > tbody > tr > form > td`. Validating seems like a pain, but it really does help you avoid issues with different browsers treating invalid markup differently (leaving you only with the hassle of how they treat *valid* markup differently :-) ).

Comment: What I meant was, I think doing what David said solved *that* issue. I never knew about the limitations of nesting forms and tables.